# Passing List of Dictionaries to Django View Using Ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am new to Ajax and Django, so I might be missing something basic here. I am trying to pass a list of dictionaries to a Django view.

Example: data = [ {'item':'itemname','qty':'qty','price','price'},{'item':'itemname','qty':'qty','price','price}, etc.
]

I have set up my Ajax call to fire when a button is pressed.

**My cart.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var userCart = grabCart();
   userCart = JSON.stringify(userCart);
   $("#Checkout").click(function(){


$.ajax({

    URL: some URL
    headers: csrf_token,  //Im passing the token using Django
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'userCart':userCart}),
    success:function(){//stuff}
    complete:function(){//stuff, but its routing to confirmation.html}
    error:function(){//stuff}
   });
});
```

**My Django view**

```
def confirmation(request):
   data = json.loads(request.POST.get('userCart')) # <-- this line is throwing the error
   print(type((data)) # this prints out list
   print(data) #this prints out the list of the dictionaries 
   return render(request,'confirmation.html')
```

*I keep getting an Error 500, Type Error. The JSON object must be str, bytes, or byte array, not NoneType*
This is confusing. The results are there but Django is throwing an error and won't render the confirmation page.

Comment: `request.POST.get('userCart')` is returning None.  This means either that `userCart` is not present in the post data at all, or it is present with an actual null value.  Try printing it before you call json.loads().

Comment: Also, in cart.js, print `userCart` to the console to see what it's sending.

Comment: console.logging the data value of {'userCart':userCart} from the js, shows that the cart is there. I can see items.
{userCart:"[{\"item\":"Food Item\",\"price\":\"10.00\", etc.}].

Ahh, I tried printing request.POST.get('userCart') first before using the json.loads and it returned None. So the userCart is not actually being passed.